# Inserir múltiplos valores com WEB API

Tags: c#, angular, entity-framework, api, asp.net-core

E ai meus queridos como estão? tranquilos? Vou resumir meu projeto para auxiliar no entendimento: estou criando um CRUD para me auxiliar em algumas tarefas da empresa. Tenho 3 areas as quais utilizo (**System**, **Database** e **SystemDatabase**). Na area **System** eu cadastro os sistemas aos quais eu utilizo na empresa, já na **Database** eu cadastro todos os bancos de dados aos quais meus sistemas podem utilizar e no **SystemDatabase** ficam armazenados os sistemas juntamente dos seus bancos de dados ativos. Estou utilizando Angular no frontend e WebAPI com ASP.NET e EF CORE no backend.

No meu formulário eu informo qual vai ser o sistema que irei dizer os bancos que estarão ativos pra ele, como um sistema pode se comunicar com vários bancos de dados, eu optei por utilizar um "multiple select" para listar todos os bancos que posso adicionar, veja abaixo:

[image: Formulário de cadastro dos sistemas]

O problema é que eu não sei ao certo como inserir esses dados na tabela, e do jeito que eu fiz não estou tendo o retorno desejado, pesquisei bastante a respeito porém não existe muito conteúdo abordando este assunto pela internet. Já li documentação da linguagem, documentação do framework, pedi ajuda pra um colega, pesquisei até em site indiano e não consegui encontrar muita coisa.

A minha lógica foi a seguinte: pensei em criar um array pra armazenar o Id de cada banco selecionado e ao salvar (executar o POST) ele rodar um `for` que fará uma verificação através de um índice e caso exista dados no array, ir adicionando no banco um por um

[image: Lógica]

Pra fazer isso, fui no meu Model e criei uma propriedade que é um array de inteiro chamada de **IdDatabases**:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace ITControl.Models
{
    public partial class SystemDatabase
    {
        public int IdSystemDatabase { get; set; }
        public int IdSystem { get; set; }
        public int IdDatabase { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public int[] IdDatabases { get; set; } // <============ AQUI
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; }
        public string UserInserted { get; set; }
        public string UserUpdated { get; set; }

        public virtual System System { get; set; }
        public virtual DataBase DataBase { get; set; }
    }
}
```

E passei essa lógica pra dentro do meu controller no `[HttpPost]`

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<SystemDatabase>> PostSystemDatabase(SystemDatabase systemDatabase)
        {
            systemDatabase.CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;
            systemDatabase.UserInserted = (HttpContext.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity).Name;


            for (int i = 0; i < systemDatabase.IdDatabases.Count(); i++)
            {
                systemDatabase.IdDatabase = systemDatabase.IdDatabases[i];
                _context.SystemDatabase.Add(systemDatabase);
            }

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetSystemDatabase", new { id = systemDatabase.IdSystemDatabase }, systemDatabase);

        }
```

O resultado que eu esperava, era que ele adicionasse um por um ele me retornasse algo mais ou menos nessa pegada no banco:

[image: Resultado Esperado]

Mas na realidade ele não adiciona um por um, ele está jogando apenas o ultimo Id no banco:

[image: Resultado Atual]

Fui nas ferramentas de desenvolvedor do navegador, olhei a resposta que ele estava me dando no network quando fazia o Post e ele me retornou o seguinte preview:

```
{IdSystemDatabase: 40, IdSystem: 3, IdDatabase: 13, IdDatabases: [1, 13],…}
CreatedAt: "2020-08-25T08:54:13.5748194-03:00"
DataBase: null
IdDatabase: 13
IdDatabases: [1, 13]
0: 1
1: 13
IdSystem: 3
IdSystemDatabase: 40
System: null
UpdatedAt: null
UserInserted: "OliveiraRBru"
UserUpdated: null
```

Ele está recebendo os Id's no `IdDatabases` porém não está registrando um por um, o que eu posso estar fazendo de errado?? To realmente perdido, acredito muito que o erro esteja dentro do meu `For`

Comment: cara pelo tamanho da sua pergunta ela parece ser especificac do seu sistema, tenta fazer uma pergunta mais concisa e especifca de um problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analisando mais a fundo e consultando alguns outros colegas, consegui resolver o erro. Eu iria desfazer a pergunta, mas como vi que não existe muita coisa na internet falando a respeito disso, irei compartilhar com vocês e deixar minha contribuição á comunidade ;D

A solução a qual encontrei foi a seguinte, removi o `IdSystemDatabase` do meu model e do meu context, já que minha tabela no banco só seria usada para armazenar o ID do sistema e do banco de dados, logo ele se tornaria inútil e também iria ficar trazendo alguns erros, então já tratei de remove-lo.

Meu model ficou da seguinte forma:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace ITControl.Models
{
    public partial class SystemDatabase
    {
        public int IdSystem { get; set; }
        public int IdDatabase { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public int[] IdDatabases { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; }
        public string UserInserted { get; set; }
        public string UserUpdated { get; set; }

        public virtual System System { get; set; }
        public virtual DataBase DataBase { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Após remover o `IdSystemDatabase` do meu context, foi necessário passar o `IdSystem` e `IdDatabase` como chave

Coloquei o seguinte no context:

```
entity.HasKey(d => new { d.IdDatabase, d.IdSystem });
```

Passados o `IdSystem` e o `IdDatabase` como chaves no context, eu alterei algumas coisas no meu `for`. Primeiro eu utilizei um `if` para verificar se não haveriam dados repetidos ou nulos, e dentro do if passei a condição que estava anteriormente direto no for. Verificando com um breakpoint anteriormente, eu tinha percebido que estava cometendo um erro, eu não estava pedindo para salvar a inserção após verificar, ele recebia o id dentro do índice, recebia o comando pra adicionar porém não recebia nada falando pra ele salvar essa inserção e por conta disso ele adicionava no banco apenas o ultimo id passado pelo índice já que era o ultimo armazenado no `IdDatabase`, somente depois que ele saia do for que iria salvar, este era o erro. Logo pra corrigir isso eu passei o `await _context.SaveChangesAsync();` pra dentro da condição do `for` ficando tudo da seguinte forma:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<SystemDatabase>> PostSystemDatabase(SystemDatabase systemDatabase)
        {
            systemDatabase.CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;
            systemDatabase.UserInserted = (HttpContext.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity).Name;

            for (int i = 0; i < systemDatabase.IdDatabases.Count(); i++)
            {
                if (_context.SystemDatabase.Where(w => w.IdSystem == systemDatabase.IdSystem
                                                 && w.IdDatabase == systemDatabase.IdDatabases[i]).FirstOrDefault() == null)
                {
                    systemDatabase.IdDatabase = systemDatabase.IdDatabases[i];
                    _context.SystemDatabase.Add(systemDatabase);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }                
            }

            return CreatedAtAction("GetSystemDatabase", systemDatabase);

        }
```

E pronto, consegui obter o resultado desejado no banco, vejam só:

[image: Resultado Certo]

E tratando os ID's pra apresentar os seus respectivos nomes no CRUD, este foi meu resultado final:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

(Censurei pois são sistemas da empresa)